# Как распарсить ответ с помощью grep?

Tags: linux, grep

Получаю информацию о винте командой

```
lshw -class disk -class storage
```

Получаю вот такой ответ:

```
*-ide:0
   description: IDE interface
   product: Cougar Point 4 port SATA IDE Controller
   vendor: Intel Corporation
   physical id: 1f.2
   bus info: pci@0000:00:1f.2
   logical name: scsi0
   version: 05
   width: 32 bits
   clock: 66MHz
   capabilities: ide pm bus_master cap_list emulated
   configuration: driver=ata_piix latency=0
   resources: irq:19 ioport:f110(size=8) ioport:f100(size=4) ioport:f0f0(size=8) ioport:f0e0(size=4) ioport:f0d0(size=16) ioport:f0c0(size=16)
 *-disk
      description: ATA Disk
      product: Hitachi HCP72503
      vendor: Hitachi
      physical id: 0.0.0
      bus info: scsi@0:0.0.0
      logical name: /dev/sda
      version: GM3O
      serial: GEK334RC3X0XMA
      size: 298GiB (320GB)
      capabilities: partitioned partitioned:dos
      configuration: ansiversion=5 signature=000d25bb
```

А как можно вывести только значения полей product и serial из раздела *-disk с помощью grep?

Comment: с помощью `grep`, пожалуй, — ни как... тут придётся сооружать что-то на `sed`/`perl`/`awk`/`python`/`bash`... или поменять вывод `lshw` на json или xml и запрашивать его утилитами...

Answer (score 2):

проще будет обратиться к первоисточнику информации — программе *linux*:

```
$ cat /sys/block/*/device/{model,wwid}
```

---

чтобы понять, из каких файлов выведены строки:

```
$ head /sys/block/*/device/{model,wwid}
```

Comment: про «из каких файлов»: мне больше нравится способ `grep . <файлы>`

Comment: А чё за `wwid`? Я у себя такого не нашёл. Может `uuid`?

Comment: На заметку: @Fat-Zer, попробуйте, кстати, добавить *-H*.

Comment: @donRumata, 1. [wikipedia](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/World_Wide_Name). 2. [linux src](https://github.com/torvalds/linux/blob/052c220da392c4dcbc628852d04970447a315683/drivers/scsi/scsi_sysfs.c#L955)

Comment: Афигеть. Не знал.

Comment: @donRumata, надеюсь, благородный дон не будет поражён в пятку, если я скажу, что сам про эту фигню узнал только вчера.

Comment: Я думаю, что даже Будах удивился бы.

Answer (score 1):

Вот так получилось:

```
lshw -class disk -class storage|grep -A12 disk|grep product|awk '{print $2" "$3" "$4}'
```

Answer (score 1):

Нечто вроде:

```
$ sudo lshw -class disk -class storage | grep -e продукт -e серийный

продукт: SB7x0/SB8x0/SB9x0 SATA Controller [IDE mode]
продукт: SB7x0/SB8x0/SB9x0 IDE Controller
продукт: Hitachi HDS72103
серийный №: JP1470HJ3EN92K
```

Вас устроит ?